# Select the rows from the table by clicking a button and update the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to create an edit button so that when it's clicked, it selects the entire row and fills the inputs above with the values from it for modifications or updates. I can't seem to make my code work for more than 3 rows because it gets stuck somewhere. In my code below, the modify button doesn't show any errors in the console so I can't figure out what I did wrong.

I'm trying to create a phone book using a dynamic table that needs to have 2 buttons, one named modify and one named delete. The problem is the modify button which doesn't seem to work. Thank you in advance.

```js
var clientList = [{
    name: "Nume1",
    lastName: "Prenume1",
    phone: ["0758066000"],
    initialOrder: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Nume3",
    lastName: "Prenume3",
    phone: ["0758000000"],
    initialOrder: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Nume2",
    lastName: "Prenume2",
    phone: ["0758000000", "0758000000"],
    initialOrder: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Nume4",
    lastName: "Prenume4",
    phone: ["075803481"],
    initialOrder: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Nume5",
    lastName: "Prenume5",
    phone: ["07942990220"],
    initialOrder: 5
  }
];

//drawing the table
function showDataInTable(arr) {
  var tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
  var tableData = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tableData += `
    <tr>
    <td>${clientList[i].name}</td>
    <td>${clientList[i].lastName}</td>
    <td>${clientList[i].phone}</td>
    <td data-index ="${i}" data-id ="modify" class="buttons1">modify</td>
    <td data-index ="${i}" data-id ="delete" class="buttons2">delete</td>
    <tr>
    `;
  }
  tableBody.innerHTML = tableData;
}
showDataInTable(clientList);

//writing the sorting function
function sort(arr, parameter, sortDirection) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

      if (sortDirection === "up") {

        if (arr[i][parameter] > arr[j][parameter]) {
          var temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = temp;
        }
      } else if (sortDirection === "down") {

        if (arr[i][parameter] < arr[j][parameter]) {
          var temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  showDataInTable(arr);
}
//table click event
document.getElementById("table").addEventListener("click", tableClicked);

var sortDirection;
var index;
var editingTable;

function tableClicked() {

  //table delete
  function delClient(arr, index) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }

  index = Number(event.target.parentElement.rowIndex - 1);

  if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "delete") {

    delClient(clientList, index);
    showDataInTable(clientList);
  }

  // table edit
  if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "modify") {
    document.getElementById("nameInput").delete = clientList[index].name;
    document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value = clientList[index].lastName;
    document.getElementById("phoneInput").value = clientList[index].phone;
    document.getElementById("submit").value = "SAVE";
  }

  //table sorting
  if (event.target.tagName == "TH") {

    var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {

      headers[i].classList.remove("selected");
    }

    event.target.classList.add("selected");

    if (sortDirection == "up") sortDirection = "down";
    else sortDirection = "up";

    var parameter = event.target.id;
    sort(clientList, parameter, sortDirection);

  }
}

// when form is clicked
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("click", formClicked);

function formClicked() {

  //add client or edit existing
  if (event.target.id == "submit") {

    event.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phoneInput").value;
    phone = phone.split(",");

    if (name && lastName && phone) {

      if (editingTable == true) {

        clientList[index].name = name;
        clientList[index].lastName = lastName;
        clientList[index].phone = phone;
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "ADD CONTACT";
        editingTable = false;

      } else {

        var newClient = {
          name: name,
          lastName: lastName,
          phone: phone
        }
        clientList.push(newClient);
      }

      //redraw the table
      showDataInTable(clientList);

      //reset input fields
      document.getElementById("nameInput").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value = "";
      document.getElementById("phoneInput").value = "";

    } else {
      alert("INPUT FIELDS ARE INCOMPLETE!");
    }
  }
}

//make sure phoneInput gets numbers 
document.getElementById("phoneInput").addEventListener("keydown", checkInput);
document.getElementById("phoneInput").addEventListener("input", checkInput);

function checkInput() {
  if (/[^0-9]/.test(event.key) && event.keyCode !== 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: dodgerblue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
}

.input {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#name {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

#lastName {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

#phone {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 250px;
}

#submit {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: white;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 69%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -1px rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.85);
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  input {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  form {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}

.selected {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: black;
}

.buttons1:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.buttons2:hover {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Agenda telefonica">
  <meta name="author" content="Adelina Lipsa">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Agenda telefonica</title>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-ioUrHig76ITq4aEJ67dHzTvqjsAP/7IzgwE7lgJcg2r7BRNGYSK0LwSmROzYtgzs" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-sri+NftO+0hcisDKgr287Y/1LVnInHJ1l+XC7+FOabmTTIK0HnE2ID+xxvJ21c5J" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="header"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>&nbsp;Phone book</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="input">
      <form id="myForm">
        <p>Nume:</p>
        <input type="text" id="nameInput">
        <p>Prenume:</p>
        <input type="text" id="lastNameInput">
        <p>Telefon:</p>
        <input type="text" id="phoneInput">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="ADD CONTACT">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table id="table">
        <thead id="thead">
          <tr>
            <th id="name">Nume <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th id="lastName">Prenume <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th id="phone">Telefon <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sidenote: arrays have a default `.sort()` method you can  pass a callback handling objects, no need to write it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to do it the hard way so that I can learn better

Comment: You mention jQuery but you're not using it. Indeed without jQuery you do it harder :)

Comment: JQuery is a matter of opinion. The first thing I did when ES6 and HTML5 came out, was getting rid of JQuery. Using jquery in the past had taught me alot of anti-patterns ( like using the HTML as your data store instead of separating data model and view ) I had to unlearn when I started coding complex apps.

Comment: @Shilly fair discussion (Although, I can argue with that for some cases ), what I tried to say that if OP using jQuery (follow the question's tags), then jQuery make the code easier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

1. You need to use `target` rather than `currentTarget` because you want to get the element the user clicked on (the button) but not the one you listen to (the table). <sup>[1]</sup>
2. `document.getElementById("nameInput").delete` should be `document.getElementById("nameInput").value`.
3. In `showDataInTable` You need to close the `tr` tag (`</tr>`) instead of open one (`<tr>`)

https://jsbin.com/taqaqor/edit?js,output

---

> <sup>[1]</sup> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its direct descendent.

<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you're switching `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` around.

Since you bind the click event to the table, the event.currentTarget equals the table, not the table cell. And the event.target is actually the table cell.

But your code expects `if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "delete")` and `if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "modify")`, whcih will always be undefined, since the data attributes are on the cell, not the table.

You would expect this to throw an error, but since both `target` and `currentTarget` exist, it does not throw.

If I change `event.currentTarget()` into `event.target()`, I can delete and modify all the rows. There's still some other issues ( like delete deleting the last element instead of the clicked one ), but that does solve the main question.